# Is it possible for the Ancient Chinese to have used itching powder as a means of torture?

Tags: humans, torture

I was thinking about Chinese water drop torture, and other forms of torture that do not cause direct physical damage. I was wondering if a form of torture where the victim is made to feeling itchy was possible.  Did such a form of torture ever exist?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As the name states, this is a community dedicated to solve worldbuilding problems, while your question seem about history of torture methods. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to make yourself familiar with our standards.

Comment: I'd hope you can restructure this question to be within the worldbuilding guidelines - give it a try! For myself, I can add that I suffer from neuropathy and neuralgia due to severe traumatic damage to a highly enervated area, and I often have a feeling like incredibly strong pins n needles and itchiness beneath the skin - it could definitely work as a means of duress.

Comment: The Chinese have been pretty ingeniously inhumane through the ages. In recent years they have used torture extensively to suppress Falun Gong practitioners (a peaceful meditation technique). They have used among many horrible tortures, one which involves tying a victim naked to a tree so that they will be bitten all over by insects. WARNING explicit diagrams (but not photos)  of torture methods. http://en.minghui.org/html/articles/2012/7/21/134517.html

Comment: With mine and @Cyn's edits, is it possible to reopen this? Or is it still off-topic?

Comment: @SoraTamashii the problem (and why I voted to close even when adding an edit) is that it's a historical question and doesn't seem to be about worldbuilding.  It appears to me to be someone musing a question and posting it instead of doing research then asking for help filling in the gaps of what s/he could find.

Comment: Understandable, and I figured as much, but thought I'd put the question out there for the sake of consideration in case it was appropriate to reopen. Didn't want to vote to reopen yet though, due to my own reservations on it.